# Google Doesn't Obey Canonical meta-tag for cross-domain

Tags: google, google-search-console, search, multiple-domains

I'm working on a website that's normally accessed trough a load-balance. But we also have direct URL to each server.

Lately, Google started to index the direct URLs to our servers, which is bad because we don't want our user to go directly to each server (if some server is taken down for maintenance).

We've correct canonical link tags pointing to the load-balance URL. All links in the sitemap.xml point to the load-balance URL. So we have no idea how Google got a hand on the direct server URLs.

To be extra clear: 
Our load-balance is `foo.com`. All the links on the site use this URL. So does the sitemap and canonical-tags.

But Google still indexes `foo.server01.webhost.com` and `foo.server02.webhost.com`

We cannot add 301-redirects from `foo.server**.webhost.com` to `foo.com` due to various reasons.

Do I have to verify that I own all the URLs in Google Search Console? Or am I missing out some other settings?

Comment: Is the user externally redirected to `foo.server01.webhost.com` - so the URL is exposed? Or is this rewritten internally (using a proxy)? "Do I have to verify that I own all the URLs in Google Search Console?" - it was my understanding that the target of a cross-domain canonical should also be a verified property in GSC, however, I can't find a reference for this at the moment. Note that the rel="canonical" is only _advisory_ so there is no guarantee that Google will use it.

Comment: No, the users are never exposed to foo.server01.webhost.com. The load balance is rewriting the response.

Comment: (I meant, target and "source" domains should be verified, not just the target.)

Comment: I'll verify that I own the source/server URLs and see if that makes any difference. Thank you! :)

Comment: I found this article https://yoast.com/rel-canonical/ where Yoast state that SearchEngineJournal has articles with canonical-tags linking back to Yoast. See "Cross domain canonical". This makes me wonder if you really have to "own" both URLs in Google Search Console.

Comment: It really all goes back to how you are load-balancing your servers and how the servers were set-up. @w3dk is correct to ask. Proxy servers are really the best way, however, if you are using round-robin techniques, then your web servers are exposed. If not set-up properly, the servers will return a header with the undesired host path.

Comment: Maybe I'm on the wrong foot but did you tried robots.txt disallow rule, and can you verify there aren't any links pointing to `foo.server01.webhost.com` in your website and if there are any have you got `rel="nofollow"` attribute for them?

Comment: @closetnoc The load balance doesn't expose any info regarding the server. I just double checked the HTTP Headers. :/

@knif3r I don't think that I can add a robots.txt file for that particular domain as the load balance is doing a reverse proxy and will return whatever is requested and served from each server.

I also Google'd to see if I could find where to links was found by Google. `site:http://foo.com "foo.server01.webhost.com"` but didn't give anything relevant. :/

Comment: What I was trying to get to is how you are load-balancing your servers. There are several ways to do this. It seems like you are using a proxy server. This is where I would be looking for a configuration error. I would also check the web servers to make sure that only foo.com appears within the web server (Apache, IIS, etc.) configuration. These are the only two places I can imagine the problem being short of a bad link somewhere.

Comment: @closetnoc We're using IIS. The applications are bound to foo.com and foo.server01.webhost.com. We need the latter to binding to do some health controls, fetch logs etc. I've inspected several request (page request, file download, images) with fiddler and nothing seems to expose foo.server01.webhost.com. Even though `foo.server01.webhost.com` got exposed by the edtiors there should be a way to force google into using the `foo.com` url. :/

Comment: You got me. It sounds like you have really examined this. Ironically, I used to manage hundreds of IIS web servers behind proxies without an issue. But that was a long time ago. Right now, I cannot think of anything more. I just know it will be that one thing hidden away that you will smack your forehead over. ;-)

Comment: I'm thinking about if-ing in an NOINDEX meta tag when the Request Host Header contains `server**.webhost.com`. Pretty much a last resort solution. Doesn't really fix the problem just mitigates it.

Answer (score 1):

> ...Lately, Google started to index the direct URLs to our servers, which is bad...

Remove the link tag with `rel="canonical"` in it and place the following tag between `<head>` and `</head>` of the HTML:

```
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX">
```

This will tell all search engines not to index the page. This should work with all search engines as some might not even understand and/or process `rel=canonical`. Then after saving the changes, give the search engines a few hours to a few weeks to process your request.

There's more information here: http://www.metatags.org/meta_name_robots

Comment: If I were to put `<meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX">` into the headers of both servers nothing will be indexed as the load balance is doing a reverse proxy. So this will effectively say to who ever visit foo.com not to index the site. 

All I want is to have google to not index `foo.server01.webhosting.com` but instead, use `foo.com` instead. That is where Canonical meta-tag comes in, as google themselves recommend to use 301 or canonical.
301 is out of the question and I'm wondering is there're any more actions when using the canonical tag.

Comment: No, you only apply that tag to the pages with duplicate content, not every page. Let search engines index original content.

Comment: Put the pages are the same. Same page but served over different domains. I'm thinking about if:ing in a NOINDEX meta tag if the Request Host header contains server**.webhosting.com. I just wished that there was a solution to this problem without doing code changes.